# Getting Error while calling invokable method from Einstein Bot

Tags: apex, invocable-method, einstein-chatbot

I am getting this error in the log when calling an invocable method from Einstein Bot.

> Error: Attribute lookup failed for invocable action
> WorkflowValidateHelper at path
> /support/conversations/0X97e0000008OPk/invocations/0SC7e0000004EA3GAM

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for the error text, but you need to please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/359921/edit) your question to also add code and information about what you have attempted so far to diagnose or correct the issue. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include **...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.** ")*

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.